# How to enable member authentication in Apache Tomcat Tribes clustering

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, tomcat7, cluster-computing

I have read the [Clustering/Session Replication HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) for Tomcat 7.  I want to configure a password to ensure that unauthorised nodes cannot join the cluster.

I was expecting that this configuration might be done on the `Cluster/Channel/Membership` element in the Tomcat server.xml, but I can't see anything in the documentation.  Is there such a feature for Tomcat?

I am looking for something similar to JGroups' AUTH protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, no.  I don't believe you can require a cluster node to authenticate, at least not in the way that you're requesting.  I'm not sure about your needs for this requirement, but here are some options that might help.

- By default, Tomcat listens via multicast for other cluster nodes on the same subnet.  Given this, you can control what nodes join the cluster with some basic network management.  For example, if you only want two nodes in the cluster, setup a subnet with only two usable IP addresses.
- You can set the `domain` attribute on the Membership tag.  This allows you to have multiple clusters on one subnet, with each unique domain representing one cluster.  It's important to note that even if you use a hard to guess domain, this is does not offer any real security.  It's just a way to break up the cluster.
- Another way to break up the cluster is to use different multicast `address` and `port` combinations.  It's similar to setting the domain attribute, in that unique address / port combinations create different clusters.  It is also similar in that it's not security, just a way to divide nodes into different clusters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  We have internal penetration tests as part of PCI DSS and the auditor complains every time he finds an open network port with no authentication.